# The background of the Jpanel is grey

Tags: java, jpanel

Im trying to create a game in java.
At the first I've made a Jpanel and made a FPS counter and the background was white.
after that I've tried to made that when you pressing ESCAPE, the Jpanel shutting down and then I've tried to make that when you pressing Space, the Background moving to green but after that, when Im trying to start, the Jpanel moving to grey background and the FPS counter has been disappear.

this is the frame class

```
public class Frame extends JFrame{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Frame();
}


public Frame(){
    new JFrame();


    this.setTitle("Tower Defence - By Sahar Haine");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    this.setUndecorated(true);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setVisible(true);


    Screen screen = new Screen(this);
    this.add(screen);
}
```

this is the screen class:

```
public class Screen extends JPanel implements Runnable{


Thread thread = new Thread(this);
Frame frame;

private int fps = 0;

public int scene;

public Boolean running = false;

public Screen(Frame frame){
    this.frame = frame; 


    this.frame.addKeyListener(new KeyHandller(this));

    thread.start();

}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.clearRect(0, 0, this.frame.getWidth(), this.frame.getHeight());

    g.drawString(fps + "", 10, 10);


    if(scene == 0){
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    }else{

    }
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    g.fillRect(0, 0, this.frame.getWidth(), this.frame.getHeight());
}



public void run() {
    System.out.println("Success");

    long lastFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int frames = 0;

    running = true;
    scene = 0;

    while(running){
        try {
            repaint();

            frames++;

            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000>= lastFrame){
                fps = frames;
                frames = 0;
                lastFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }


            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Screen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    System.exit(0);
}




public class KeyTyped{
    public void keyESC(){
       running = false;

}

    public void keySPACE() {
      scene = 1;
    }
```

and this is the key handler class:

```
public class KeyHandler implements KeyListener{

private Screen screen;
private Screen.KeyTyped keyTyped;


public KeyHandler(Screen screen){
    this.screen = screen;
    this.keyTyped = this.screen.new KeyTyped();

}



public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}


public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

    System.out.println(e.getKeyCode());

    if(keyCode == 27){
        this.keyTyped.keyESC();

    }

    if(keyCode == 27){
        this.keyTyped.keySPACE();

    }
}


public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue that jumps out immediately is that you have hard coded "keyCode = 27" for both Escape and Space which is not correct.  "27 - Escape" and "32 - Space". Rather than hard code the values, please use KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE and KeyEvent.VK_SPACE as documented here, [KeyEvents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_ESCAPE)

**EDIT 1**

Also make certain that you draw the string AFTER the "Fill" or else the "Fill" will over paint the FPS string and you will not see it.

Comment: LoL i fix it but it still in a grey backround and the FPS counter not appearing

Comment: Added Edit 1 with clarity on why FPS is being overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to call

```
 super.paintComponent(g)
```

as the first line in your paintComponent method override.